# Is Carrierwave thread-safe?

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq and Carrierwave to upload images to S3. The background job does the following things:

1. Downloads image from a remote url;
2. Resizes it using minimagick;
3. Uploads the resized images to S3.

Here's the code snippet:

```
  def store_for_mobile(file)
     self.class.process optimize: [1080, 810]
     %w(android ios).each do |device|
        @directory = File.join('banners/mobile', device)
        store!(file)
     end
  end

  def store_for_web(file)
     self.class.process optimize: [750, 562]
     @directory = 'stores/750x562/'
     store!(file)
  end

  def store_header(file)
    self.class.process resize_to_limit: [640, 640]
    @directory = 'headers/images/consumer_app_brand_logos/'
    store!(file)
  end

  def store_header_mailer(file)
    self.class.process resize_to_limit: [360, 120]
    @directory = 'headers/images/360x120/'
    store!(file)
  end
```

The above methods are executed in different jobs respectively, which means sometimes they are running concurrently.

Soon I noticed that some images resized by `store_header_mailer` were uploaded to the directory which should be owned by `store_for_mobile`, `store_for_web` and `store_header`. (e.g. `'headers/images/consumer_app_brand_logos/'` got 120x120 images)

This issue didn't exist while I was using Resque.

I looked into carrierwave's source code, and noticed that

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb#L54

it is using class variables `self.processors` and class methods `self.process` while invoking image_magick command lines.

Is this part of code thread-safe? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a few days to figure out what's going on. It is kinda an interesting case and also too long to explain it here so I decided to write a [post](https://linyaoli.github.io/#/notes/2018-11-02-carrierwave-is-not-thread-safe) for it, so for more details please read it there.

---

Long story short is, carrierwave uses class variable to save processor method and dimensions, and it is not reset after the uploader finishes, thus the next uploader will be affected.